# Accessing TeamCity Agent system properties in a shell script

Tags: teamcity

I have a requirement where I need to write a shell script to stop teamcity agents on a server(3 agents per linux server). I need to get the system property; agent.name OR configuration parameter teamcity.agent.name in a shell script OR
All the agents running on a linux agent, via script or API

Answer (score 3):

Build parameters can be accessed from any build script. This is from TeamCity documentation:

> Any user-defined build parameter (system property or environment
>   variable) can reference other parameters by using the following
>   format:
>
> %[env|system].property_name% For example:
>   system.tomcat.libs=%env.CATALINA_HOME%/lib/*.jar

If you need to access build properties outside the build step, it may be done by reading the content of file which name is stored in TEAMCITY_BUILD_PROPERTIES_FILE environment variable.

For more details:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/74847308

Comment: Thanks, I need to get these parameters in a shell script which would run as a command line runner. when i try to do this $ echo ${agent.name}; in the TC agent server i do not get any output

Comment: You should use echo %agent.name%

Comment: The key here is that %varname% works in linux shells too.